# Monitoring Processes (child, grand, great grand ....) in Windows

Tags: windows

How to track what all processes my process has created. The problem is not tracking the immediate child process but rather is to track the grand child or great grand child supposing the linking process between my process and the grand child process has finished.
eg My Process is A ,it created B,and B created C.Now B has ended.so how willl i now know that C is a process that was started by me.And this might not be for only three levels it might be for even more.

Comment: You do this using a job object.  Search for CreateJobObject on MSDN (and here!) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Windows Sysinternals can show process tree.